# Python logging handler object lifetime

Tags: python, logging, handler, lifetime

I have a hopefully simple question. I want to add a custom logging handler to my python and I can't find out if the logging handler is created at application init and lives for the life of the application, if the handler is created on demand and then lives from that point on, or if the object is created on demand, torn down, and then recreated on next demand.

I'm hoping someone has experience with this and can provide an answer. Thanks.

Comment: The handler is created when you call its constructor, or when the logging is configured if you're specifying custom handler class in config. Once attached to the logger, the handler instance will live until it is removed from the handlers list or the logger is destroyed.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you much!

Comment: Glad I could help!